# how to parse json array into postgresql array type?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, parsing

Arrays seem really simple in PostgreSQL, but I am having trouble with JSON parsing into an array column type.

The Json data contains a property with an array value:

```
"problems": ["/problems/22", "/problems/31"],
```

The table has an array-type column like:

```
CREATE TABLE X(
  problems TEXT[],
  ...
);
```

The parsing generally works, eg.:

```
t.items->>'problems'  --ok
```

returns:

```
["/problems/22", "/problems/31"]
```

Then I tried this that does not work:

```
t.items->>'problems'::text[]  --error, malformed
```

Then I replaced in the json the [] by {} to adhere to PostgreSQL array syntax:

```
replace(replace(t.items->>'problems', '[', '{'), ']', '}')::text[]  --ok
```

While this is 'workable', I feel that it is a kludge. In any case, this is ugly, and not in the style of the otherwise elegant way of PostgreSQL.

How do I correctly parse the JSON into the TEXT[] array-type column?

Comment: What is `-->`? Did you mean `->>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to fill the column problems by the json element *problems*, if that what you want then use `json_array_elements_text` combined with `ARRAY` to cast a json array into list of text values `TEXT[]`

```
update mytable t
set problems = (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT json_array_elements_text(t.items->'problems')))
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/X7SJ-VIP) :

```
select 
  (SELECT ARRAY(
     SELECT json_array_elements_text(t.items->'problems')
  ))::text[] problems
from (
  select '{"problems": ["/problems/22", "/problems/31"]}'::json items
) t
```

output:

```
problems                   |
---------------------------+
{/problems/22,/problems/31}|
```

Comment: sorry I added the fiddle to the answer, but your fiddle was exactly what I was looking for. By formatting it a bit, I made the text layout narrower to make it easier to read without horizontal scrollbar, also it made me easier to understand

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`json_arrray_elements_text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to iterate the array, then aggregate it back into an array:

```
SELECT array_agg(value)
FROM json_array_elements_text(
  ('{"problems": ["/problems/22", "/problems/31"]}'::json)->'problems'
);
```

You'd do this in a subquery if the json value comes from a relation.

However, there is a simpler approach if your JSON object contains a property which already has the same shape as the `X` target table - use [`json_populate_record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM json_populate_record(NULL::X, '{"problems": ["/problems/22", "/problems/31"]}'::json);
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WC9Rnpca))</sup>

Comment: I feel your answer is useful and someday I will understand i, I find this json / sql matter complex. The other answer I can directly apply to my project, but yours is certainly useful too. Thanks.